# Selenium webElement.clear() doesn't work with phantomJS but yes with Firefox

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to use PhantomJS as a browser to make a selenium test, but I have a problem with an input.
This input is a calendar (is not type date, is text but modified by JavaScript).

First of all, I have this using FirefoxDriver and works perfectly:

```
webElement.Clear();
webElement.SendKeys(date);
```

but, using PhantomJSDriver jumps an exception which says this:

```
{"errorMessage":"Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Close","Content-Length":"0","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:53291"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"","url":"/clear","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"clear","directory":"/","path":"/clear","relative":"/clear","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/clear","queryKey":{},"chunks":["clear"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/a1e4cdb0-b901-11e4-befc-c3b28b46e8f3/element/%3Awdc%3A1424437741971/clear"}}
```

is very extraneous because in Firefox works perfectly,
what can I do to send the data?

Also I tried to sen this data without clear it, but the default value is 20/02/2015 and when i send something just add after the current text: 20/02/201530/03/2015 and doesn't work.

attribute `.text` doesn't has setter, the same for `getAttribute()`.

thanks for all,

Ivan.

@edit1: html

```
<input type="text" aria-haspopup="true" title="" value="20/02/2015" name="id0" id="id0" class="bg datetime hasDatepicker">
```

Comment: Can you provide the `html` as well?

Comment: try webElement.Click() instead of Clear

Comment: `.Click()` works perfectly

Comment: do the usage of click solve the issue ?

Comment: nono, sorry, I said that the event click works without problem

Comment: finally i solved this sending the info by javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found how to do this, probably is not the best way, but in my case works.

I send the data by JavaScript with javascriptExecutor

`((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('id0').value='" + date+ "'");`